# Listing a small quantity of files from a large directory

Tags: php, windows

I have a folder with approximately 10,000 files.  About every 0.5-2 hours, a new file appears, which indicates to me that a process has completed.  I want to use this indicator to track how many processes were complete each day and show that number on a TV, however every method I've tried seems extremely slow.

I've tried several different methods found on SO (glob, scandir, DirectoryIterator, etc.), and none can do it quickly (at least IMO).  The searches usually take about 30 seconds and/or timeout. I'd like the search to take less than 5 seconds if possible, so that run it every 5 minutes or so and show it on a TV screen semi-live.

I only need to know which files were added on the current day, and nothing else.  I could even get away with listing the first 50 files along with there getmtime, and parse from there, however all of the methods above have to cycle through each file in the directory anyways.

My last ditch method would be to use Robotask to move new files to another folder daily (and then clear it out at 12:00), but I would like to do this all with PHP if possible.

Anybody got any ideas?  Seems like every way I search this I end up with the same 4-5 SO threads with using the above methods.

Comment: How do the files "Appear" is it through some code? Why not have that code notify your endpoint as well?

Comment: Reading the contents of a directory containing 10k files will take its time, there’s little you can do about that. Different ways of reading the directory in PHP are likely not going to make any significant difference. Setting this up on file system/OS level, using inotify or something comparable, might be a better option.

Comment: @nerdlyist The files are saved from another computer (data logger).

Comment: @CBroe That's kind of what I figured, but I was hoping to try at least one more option.

Answer (score 0):

Move the archive to a new folder. When PHP runs, have it count the files in the current folder, update a file count somewhere, and move these 'new files' to the archive.

this all depends on why the files are there... but some flavor of this should work. 
Do you need to go back and see what completed last thursday?

the basic issue is that the inbox and the archive are co-mingled and the archive has become large enough that the dual purposing of a single folder is  now a problem.